# How to change/swap the layout of a widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on an application in which I need to change the layout of my current tab when a radio button is pressed.

I am using the following code to swap the layout:

```
changed_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
label1 = new QLabel(string);
delete main_layout;
changed_layout->addWidget(label1);
setLayout(changed_layout);
```

But when I click the button the software exits (crashes).

Comment: Could you tell why do you need to change the layout? And what layout are you using before you want to change to QVBoxLayout?

Comment: I am using VBoxLayout and i want to change the content of a tab.

Comment: Then do not to delete the layout. Delete the old content and create new content. Or if possible, create all widgets at startup and just show/hide widgets according to the radio button state (or use QStackedLayout http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstackedlayout.html ).

Comment: Is the radio button a child of the layout that you are deleting?

Comment: @Roku: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to directly delete `QObjects` with `delete`, call `ojbect->deleteLater()` and set your pointer to `null`. The Qt framework will safely delete the object after any slots have been exited and control has returned to the event loop.

In your code, change the line `delete main_layout;` to:

```
main_layout->deleteLater();
main_layout = NULL;
```

**Update:**
The comment from Steve S is correct. To quote Qt docs for `setLayout()`..

> If there already is a layout manager
>   installed on this widget, QWidget
>   won't let you install another. You
>   must first delete the existing layout
>   manager (returned by layout()) before
>   you can call setLayout() with the new
>   layout.layout.

Since `setLayout()` is a special case of reparenting widgets, we must delete the old layout first and then set the new layout. We would have to be very sure of the signal/slot call stack we are in to call `delete()`.

An alternative would be to setup the new layout as much as possible and then connect a slot to the old layouts `destroyed()` signal and then call `deleteLater()` on it. In the slot for the destroyed() signal you should be able to call `setLayout()` with the new layout.

If this sounds complicated, it's because it is. Changing and destroying layouts at runtime is unusual. If I found that I had to do something like this, I would probably create something like a gridLayout at the top of the hierarcy with the different layouts I would need set inside it and then move the child widgets from layout to layout without having to create and destroy them at runtime.

Comment: Unless `deleteLater()` immediately removes the layout from its widget (yikes!), this won't work in the original code.  You have to remove (delete) the old layout before calling `setLayout()`.